# Sukkah floor ideas?

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkah, architecture-design

I saw this question posted to a community email group, and it was interesting enough that I thought I would (adapt and) post it here.

Does anyone have any clever ideas for what to use for a Sukkah floor?

Many people are able to build their Sukkoth on either a wooden deck or a concrete patio, but some have to use a dirt/grass area. This, naturally, leads to concerns about rain and resultant mud/wetness, as well as just generally sinking into the floor.

It would be especially nice also if there were a way to dry it easily and well after a rain.

Any fantastic solutions?

Comment: Re "a dirt/grass area. This, naturally, leads to concerns about rain and resultant mud/wetness, as well as just generally sinking into the floor": another concern is that furniture wobbles on uneven ground, and/or that a table on uneven ground slopes and things can slide. Uneven-ground concerns aren't necessarily alleviated (though they may be) by covering the ground with a floor. Do you wish such concerns addressed by answers also? If not, perhaps exclude them explicitly, since your current main question is worded "Does anyone have any clever ideas for what to use for a Sukkah floor?".

Comment: @msh210, I'm not sure what the objection is.  If someone has a solution that will solve all of those issues, then great.  I think sloping is a problem that won't be alleviated by anything short of building a deck.  If someone is creative enough to solve that issue, however, then I welcome that answer.  I have a friend who has his Sukkah on his front yard.  He uses no floor.  His table, however, seems stable enough and level enough that slight unevenness caused by nature in the grass/soil doesn't impact it much.

Comment: @msh210 Such issues can possibly present problems for using the furniture on Shabbat and Yom Tov.

Answer (score 6):

I have never actually used it as my sukka is built on cement, but you can get Campsite flooring ([For example, maybe in a different color](http://www.kmart.com/venture-outdoors-campsite-flooring/p-089W032037910001P) or [a different option](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0091W225Y)).

Many of these camp mats dry quickly, allow water to drain properly, can be staked down, and shouldn't kill your grass (hopefully).

Edit: [Here](http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/product/index.jsp?productId=57121196) is a link where you can actually buy the stuff.

Edit 2:[For a more heavy duty option](http://www.snaplockdancefloors.com/) what about something like this.

Comment: I just came back from a camping trip where we did something like that.  It wasn't exactly that; what we got was sold as outdoor carpet.  But it was something we could hose down at the end.

Comment: While it is waterproof, it does not seem as though this will provide the stability I'm looking for (the "as well as just generally sinking into the floor" part of the problem). Remember, a dining table of sorts, as well as a number of chairs, will be used.  A Sukkah is, at least in part, an outdoor dining room, after all. For sleeping in the Sukkah, this solution can be very useful, so if you have a multi-room Sukkah, with a sleeping room on the grass and the dining room on pavement, this might be a great solution. +1, but it only solves half the problem.

Comment: Although, having said that, maybe making a partial floor - just for the table - could work. The table may be stabilized that way, and since it won't be contending with the weight of several family members, it may not face the instability problems I envision.

Comment: @SethJ Most of these products (see http://www.kmart.com/norsk-multi-purpose-campsite-flooring/p-089W007422751001P) are multiple interlocking pieces. I am pretty sure that you wouldnt really sink into these products, some of them are thick rubber. If you want something a little nicer looking (and presumably stronger) take a look at this http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/outdoor/21957/ it actually looks pretty nice, though it is for a more solid surface, so it might be best to put it on a big sheet of plywood.

Answer (score 4):

You could get a tarp and instead of just lying it in the floor you could attach it to the lower parts of the walls, to keep the grass beneath relatively dry and prevent water from running in to the sukkah. Make sure the tarp is relatively taut, and get a squigy mop for puddles that come through the roof!

Answer (score 2):

You could try laying pavers or other flat stones / slate over the grass or dirt, if your area is somewhat even. If it is isn't even, you may have to put gravel or a layer of soil to cover the area and smooth it down before laying the pavers.

My driveway is dirt and gravel, but the majority of it is even, fortunately. I do a get a bit of ponding after a heavy rain, but it usually dries or drains out after an hour or two after raining.

Answer (score 2):

A relative of mine uses plywood boards laid out on some 2x4 beams. You only have to level the beams and the floor is as good as indoors.

Comment: What happens in a storm? Is it more susceptible to being knocked over than a Sukkah built on a patio?

Comment: @SethJ Being on the ground and near a building should make it less susceptible, I think.